# Go Regexp: Match full word or substring or not at all

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying to find a way with Go to match a pattern with a `regexp.Regexp`.

The following criteria are given for the match:

1. It must either match `FooBar` or it's substring `Foo` at the beginning of the line or not at all.
2. If it matches in #1, either match must have other characters following (i.e. `\S+`)

So, it should match, e.g.:

- match: `FooABC`
- match: `FooBarABC`
- not match: `FooBar` (because no other characters are following)
- not match: `ABC` (because it does not start with `Foo`)

I tried various expressions, but can't seem to get my head around it.

I found that there is negative lookahead pattern in other implementations, but Go doesn't seem to provide it. Is there an alternative to work around this issue?

See (updated): https://regex101.com/r/SWSTzv/3

I am aware that this can obviously be solved without the use of `regexp`. However, the purpose of this request is to understand whether this problem can be solved with Go's stdlib implementation.

Comment: Maybe `(?i)^(?:Foo(?:[^b\n]ar|b[^a\n]r|ba[^r\n]|[^b\n][^a\n]r|b[^a\n][^r\n]|[^b\n]a[^r\n]|[^b\n][^a\n][^r\n]|.{0,2}$|.{4,}$)|FooBar.)`? Note you do not need `\n`s in the final regex pattern, it is only for the [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SWSTzv/2).

Comment: "It must either match FooBar or it's substring Foo or not at all ... It must have other characters following the match ...  should not match FooBar (since there's no characters following)."  Yes there are.  It matches `Foo` with following characters `Bar`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your comment. Can you please expand on the magic behind your pattern? Thanks

Comment: He, @WiktorStribiżew, created a whitelist of allowed combinations of `b`, `a`, and `r`. If you wanted to disallow a 20-char word then the regex will grow exponentially.

Comment: Realistically, if you have access to the Golang programming then you should do a check that the string is **not** `FooBar` and matches `^Foo`

Comment: Your request is contradictory : `It must either match FooBar or it's substring Foo or not at all.` and `it should match e.g. FooABC or FooBarABC`. So should it only match the Foo (resp. FooBar) part of FooABC (resp. of FooBarABC) ? If it's not a problem to match also the rest of the string you can try `^(?:Foo[^B\s]|FooB[^a]|FooBa[^r]|FooBar\S).*$` https://regex101.com/r/Jw6fP9/1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Not exponentially, but linearly. Checking for words of other lengths requires 2 alternatives: `.{1,19}` and `.{21,}`; checking for words of the same length requires 20 alternatives: `[^<c1>].{19}`, `.[^<c2>].{18}`, ..., `.{19}[^<c20>]`.

Comment: Right, my pattern can be re-written the way  I already used in another well-known post ("regex everything but").

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Of course I worked around this issue for now. I am just wondering if there is a regex only solution for this problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kpym I updated the wording to make my request more precise, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @m0r0n So, if I understand your request well, my initial solution should work because you want to match the entire line if the beginning respects your requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just invert the result of matching with the regular expression `^Foo(?:Bar)?$` (okay, not just)?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  re := regexp.MustCompile(`^Foo(?:Bar)?$`)
  str := `Foo
FooBar
FooA
FooB
FooBa
FooBax
FooBxr
FooBarAbc
FooBarFoo
ABC
AbcFooBar`

  for _, s := range strings.Split(str, "\n") {
    if strings.HasPrefix(s, "Foo") && !re.MatchString(s) {
      fmt.Println(s)
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
FooA
FooB
FooBa
FooBax
FooBxr
FooBarAbc
FooBarFoo
```

Try it on [rextester](https://rextester.com/edit/FXBDE44179).

**Update**
A solution that is more based on regular expressions and uses [*the trick*](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick).

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "regexp"
  "strings"
)

func main() {
  re := regexp.MustCompile(`^Foo$|^FooBar$|^(Foo.+)`)
  str := `Foo
FooBar
FooA
FooB
FooBa
FooBax
FooBxr
FooBarAbc
FooBarFoo
ABC
AbcFooBar`

  for _, s := range strings.Split(str, "\n") {
    submatches := re.FindStringSubmatch(s)
    if submatches != nil && submatches[1] != "" {
      fmt.Println(submatches[1])
    }
  }
}
```

Try it on [rextester](https://rextester.com/SODXZT76633).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, your implementation also matches `ABC`, which as per requirement #1 should not match at all, because the minimum requirement is the existence of `Foo`.

Comment: @m0r0n, take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: It requires a little extra code, but this solves the issue. Nice trick

Answer (score 3):

For something like this, [why do you need a regular expression?](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

A simple function like this:

```
func hasFooOrFooBarPrefix(s string) bool {
    if strings.HasPrefix(s, "FooBar") && len(s) > 6 {
        r, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s[6:])
        return !unicode.IsSpace(r)
    }
    if strings.HasPrefix(s, "Foo") && len(s) > 3 {
        r, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(s[3:])
        return !unicode.IsSpace(r)
    }
    return false
}
```

Is likely going to be at least as performant as a regular expression.

https://goplay.tools/snippet/aWUiaLzR4hm

Comment: Thanks for your response. As explained in my comments on my question, I'm wondering if there is an actual `regexp` solution to this. I adjusted my Question to make it clearer and gave an upvote to your answer, since it's a very clean and straight forward alternative implementation.